# Using a voltmeter to measure RMS value of a sine signal with a DC offset

Tags: multimeter, rms, voltmeter

Imagine you have a periodic signal F which is nothing but a sinewave (S) plus some DC offset (D).

Here is an illustration of such signal:

[image]

Imagine I want to measure the RMS value of this signal F.

The rms value of this signal mathematically can be written as:

rms_of_F = sqrt[ (rms_of_S)^2 + D^2 ]

So far so good.

First of all, if I use the DC settings of a voltmeter I would obviously not read the rms value.

Then I may use AC settings.. But recently I came to a question: [What value does ammeter or voltmeter measures (RMS, Average or Peak )?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18368/what-value-does-ammeter-or-voltmeter-measures-rms-average-or-peak)
where the answer is chosen as follows:

> Measuring RMS values is a bit more expensive than measuring average
>   values, so most multimeters avoid the former. Instead they presume
>   your signal is a sine and measure the average value for the rectified
>   sine or the peak value, after which they apply a conversion factor to
>   find the presumed RMS value.

Does that mean the rms value of my signal F can never be mesured accurately by using a voltmeter?

I'm asking because in case the voltmeter in AC settings doesn't measure the rms value: if one calibrates an instrument and relate the rms value of such signal output to the device reading(any parameter like temperature, flow ect.); 
and if another person would use a multimeter/voltmeter to use the calibration expression, this could lead him a wrong conclusion because he will not read the true rms voltage but something else.
Is that right?

Comment: This is true for "cheap" voltmeters. True RMS meters can be bought which give you the correct RMS for any measured wave.

Comment: Added to the accuracy problem is the frequency - a cheap meter will be good for 50/60 Hz sinewaves but if the frequency is in the hundreds of Hz or above then it will progressively worsen its accuracy.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for additional info. But I wanted to be sure what I wrote and conclusion is right. Do you agree the concerns and info in the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily measure the RMS value of a sine wave + offset using a cheap multimeter.

Most cheap (non-RMS-reading) multimeters are AC-coupled on the AC voltage ranges, so you would read the correct RMS value of the ripple **only** on an AC range, assuming the ripple is sinusoidal, due to the correction factor which is applied. If you happen to have one that's not AC coupled, just stick a large value film cap in series (such that Xc << input resistance of your meter).

Reading the voltage on a DC-volts range will give you the correct average value of the total signal. That also happens to be the RMS value of the offset, assuming a sinusoidal ripple.

The RMS value of the total (refer to [this](http://masteringelectronicsdesign.com/how-to-derive-the-rms-value-of-a-sine-wave-with-a-dc-offset/) derivation if you need proof) is just the quadrature sum of the two components:

\$V_{RMS} = \sqrt{V_{DC}^2 +  V_{AC}^2}\$

In your example, you would read 10.00V on the DC range and 0.707V on the AC range, so the RMS value would be 10.03V.

Comment: So basically the AC settings calculate Rms of the ripple which is the standard deviation around the mean?

Comment: The meter displays a value equal to the RMS value of the ripple, **provided it's a sine wave**- because what is actually displayed is 1.11 * |Vin - Vav|, averaged. 1.11 is pi/(2*sqrt(2)).  It does not actually calculate the RMS value.