# When we talk about AC current, is it peak current value or average value?

Tags: current, ac, current-measurement, multimeter

When we talk about AC current, is it peak current value or average value?

Also when we measure AC current with a multimeter or a clamp meter, is it peak or average?

I mean, if with a multimeter I measure a 1A current under AC110V, is 1A an equivalent value, and does it mean it is 110W like DC?

My multimeter dealer says the measured AC current is standard deviation. It confuses me more.

Comment: check https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18368/what-value-does-ammeter-or-voltmeter-measures-rms-average-or-peak

Comment: I think standard deviation means AC RMS or something like that. Check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G8Qoj3TpO9A&ab_channel=EEVblog

Comment: So, when we say the voltage from a wall socket is 110V 60Hz, is it 110V RMS or 110V peak?

Answer (score 0):

> When we talk about AC current, is it peak current value or average value?

Typically, when someone says that there is, say, 10A of current (AC) flowing through a load, they mean 10A AC RMS.

The average value of a pure sine wave signal is zero.

> Also when we measure AC current with a multimeter or a clamp meter, is it peak or average?

Multimeters and clampmeters measure RMS

> I mean, if with a multimeter I measure a 1A current under AC110V, is 1A an equivalent value, and does it mean it is 110W like DC?

Yes. That is exactly why we use RMS instead of peak.

Comment: Does this mean that AC110V 60 Hz from a wall socket is in fact 110V RMS？And RMS volage multiplies RMS current is power?

Comment: yes, that is correct